# Android Studio with Libgdx : Sound effect is not working properly on touch and touchdrag event

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am creating a game which has two specific Methods to control the actor. Method 1- jump, and method 2- jump_higher. And the same sound play on the action.
For handling the input, I am using an InputHandler class which makes use of import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
And the code as Follows:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
/*some other imports*/

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {
/* Variable declaration and constructor*/


@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
    Actor.jump();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (Gdx.input.getDeltaY() < -20) {
        Actor.jump_higher();
    }
    return true;
}}
```

and in my Actor class:

```
public class Bird {
/* Variable declaration and constructor*/

 public void jump() {
    if (isAlive){
        AssetLoader.JUMP.play();
        velocity.y = -700;
    }
}

public void jump_higher() {
    if (isAlive){
        AssetLoader.JUMP.play();
        velocity.y = -1050;
    }
}}
```

As the touchDown action makes the actor jump, and jump method playing the sound.
The game is running perfectly except the sound on jump_higher event. On touchDragged event, sound isn't playing properly, its sounds as BURRRRRRPS (sorry for not proper word). As it is taking all the drag way input as touchDown. I just want to play the sound only once on each event. Need help regarding the proper way to implement the touch event.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag for your requirement :

```
boolean isHigherJump;
```

And use this flag inside `jump_higher()` method

```
public void jump_higher() {
    if (isAlive){
        if(!isHigherJump){
           AssetLoader.JUMP.play();
           isHigherJump=true;
        }
        velocity.y = -1050;
    }
}}
```

reset your flag in `touchUp(..)` method of `InputProcessor`

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    Actor.isHigherJump=false;
    return false;
}
```